# How can I check the value of the Next Row while looping using PHP/MYSQL?

Tags: php

I got previousRow of record using this code

```
<?php
  $previousRow = array();
  while ($temp = mysql_fetch_row($res2)) 
 {

     echo "<br>currentRow:".$temp[1];
     echo "previousRow:".$previousRow[1];
     $previousRow = $temp; 

  } 
 ?>
```

### oupout

currentRow:1previousRow:

currentRow:5previousRow:1

currentRow:6previousRow:5

currentRow:7previousRow:6

currentRow:8previousRow:7

How can I check the value of the next row replaced by Previous Row ?

Any help would be grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get you correctly, then something like this would help?

```
$previousRow = array();
$currentRow = mysql_fetch_row($res2);

while ($currentRow) {
    $nextRow = mysql_fetch_row($res2);

    echo "<br>currentRow:".$currentRow[1];
    echo "previousRow:".$previousRow[1];
    echo "nextRow:".$nextRow[1];

    $previousRow = $currentRow;
    $currentRow = $nextRow;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try code given below.

```
$res = array();
while ($result = mysql_fetch_row($r)) {
    $res[] = $result;
 }
 echo "<pre>";
 foreach($res AS $index=>$res1){
     echo "Current".$res1[1]; 
     echo "  Next" . $res[$index+1][1];
     echo "  Prev" . $res[$index-1][1]; echo "<br>";
 }
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'd collect all the rows first, then walk through them with a for:

```
<?php
$rows = array();
while ($temp = mysql_fetch_row($res2)) 
{
    $rows[] = $temp;
}
$rowCount = count($rows);
for ($i = 0; $i < $rowCount; $i++) {
     echo "<br>currentRow:".$rows[$i][1];
     if ($i > 0) {
         echo "previousRow:".$rows[$i - 1][1];
     }
         if ($i + 1 < $rowCount - 1) {
             echo "nextRow:".$rows[$i + 1][1];
         }
} 
?>
```